# microphone sph0645 with I2S less sensitive after watchdog sleep with Adafruit Feather M0

Tags: arduino, sleep, microphone, adafruit

I am using the Adafruit Feather M0 RFM69 with the Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone Breakout SPH0645. Every second I take a reading (sampleRate = 16000, bits per sample = 32) using the I2S library and send it over the radio. This all works fine.

My problem is that, when I want to save power, I am getting weird readings after I wake the board from sleep (using Adafruit_SleepyDog library). The microphone somewhat still works, although it is much less sensitive, only picks up loud sounds and also returns 60dB in a quiet room. When I don't put it to sleep, in the same sound setting, I get 40dB. However, if I put a delay of 250ms after waking up, the microphone works fine again, like before, but this is obviously not saving energy then.

I wonder why this is happening. Is there something I can do to get the microphone to work quicker? I checked the datasheet, but it only says: "When Vdd is applied the microphone senses the
CLOCK line, if the frequency is greater than 900KHz, the microphone enters the normal mode of operation." This should not even take a few ms though?
Thanks in advance

```
#include <I2S.h>
#include <Adafruit_SleepyDog.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF69.h>


/************ Radio Setup ***************/
#define RF69_FREQ 433.0
#define SLEEP

//#if defined(ARDUINO_SAMD_FEATHER_M0) // Feather M0 w/Radio
  #define RFM69_CS      8
  #define RFM69_INT     3
  #define RFM69_RST     4
  #define LED           13
//#endif

// radio
// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF69 rf69(RFM69_CS, RFM69_INT);
int transmit_interval = 1000;
int time_counter = 0;
int packetnum = 0;

// MIC
#define SAMPLES 1024//2048 // make it a power of two for best DMA performance
int samples[SAMPLES];
int measurementsdB = 0;
int current_measure;
#define ADC_SOUND_REF 65
#define DB_SOUND_REF 41

int sampleRate1 = 16000;
int bitsPerSample1 = 32;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t measurementdB = 123;
  uint8_t battery = 111;
  uint8_t test = 222;
} RadioMessage;
RadioMessage struct_message;

void setup()
{
  delay(2000); // Wait so its easier to program
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //while (!Serial) { delay(1); } // wait until serial console is open, remove if not tethered to computer

  // Init Mic 
  if (!I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, sampleRate1, bitsPerSample1)) {
      while (1); // do nothing
  }

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);     
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  pinMode(RFM69_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);

  Serial.println("Feather RFM69 TX Test!");
  Serial.println();

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);

  if (!rf69.init()) {
    Serial.println("RFM69 radio init failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("RFM69 radio init OK!");
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb250Fd250, +13dbM (for low power module)
  // No encryption
  if (!rf69.setFrequency(RF69_FREQ)) {
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
  }

  // If you are using a high power RF69 eg RFM69HW, you *must* set a Tx power with the
  // ishighpowermodule flag set like this:
  rf69.setTxPower(20, true);  // range from 14-20 for power, 2nd arg must be true for 69HCW

  // The encryption key has to be the same as the one in the server
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
  rf69.setEncryptionKey(key);

  Serial.print("RFM69 radio @");  Serial.print((int)RF69_FREQ);  Serial.println(" MHz");

  //GCLK->GENCTRL.bit.RUNSTDBY=1; // !! can go
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println("START");
///// MIC
  //PM->APBCMASK.reg |= PM_APBCMASK_I2S;
  int a = 0;
  while (a == 0) a = I2S.available();

  uint8_t current_measure = sample_audio_signal(samples);

///// RADIO
  if (true)//((time_counter + transmit_interval) < millis())
  {
    struct_message.measurementdB = current_measure;   
    //struct_message.battery = measuredvbat;   
    // Send a message!
    /*
    Serial.print("Array content: ");
    uint8_t* bla = (uint8_t*) &struct_message;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(bla[i]);
    }*/

    rf69.send((const uint8_t*) &struct_message, sizeof(struct_message));
    rf69.waitPacketSent();
    Serial.print("Wait for reply");
    // Now wait for a reply
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

    if (rf69.waitAvailableTimeout(100))  {
      // Should be a reply message for us now   
      if (rf69.recv(buf, &len)) {
        Serial.print("Got a reply: ");
        Serial.println((char*)buf);
      } else {
        Serial.println("Receive failed");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("No reply, is another RFM69 listening?");
    }
    Serial.println("Radio sleeping");
    rf69.sleep();
    time_counter = millis();
  }
  // sleep time
  #ifdef SLEEP
   int sleepMS = Watchdog.sleep(10);
   delay(250);
  #else
    delay(1000);
  #endif

  Serial.println("loop ended");
}

void Blink(byte PIN, byte DELAY_MS, byte loops) {

  for (byte i=0; i<loops; i++)  {
    digitalWrite(PIN,HIGH);
    delay(DELAY_MS);
    digitalWrite(PIN,LOW);
    delay(DELAY_MS);
  }
}

float sample_audio_signal(int samples[])
{

  for (int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++) {
    int sample = 0;
    while ((sample == 0) || (sample == -1) ) {

      sample = I2S.read();
    }
    // convert to 18 bit signed
    sample >>= 14;
    samples[i] = sample;

  }

  // ok we have the samples, get the mean (avg)
  float meanval = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++) {
    meanval += samples[i];
  }
  meanval /= SAMPLES;

  // subtract it from all samples to get a 'normalized' output
  for (int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++) {
    samples[i] -= meanval;
  }

  // find the 'peak to peak' max
  float maxsample, minsample;
  minsample = 100000;
  maxsample = -100000;
  for (int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++) {
    minsample = min(minsample, samples[i]);
    maxsample = max(maxsample, samples[i]);
  }

  int newdB = 20 * log10((float)maxsample / (float)ADC_SOUND_REF) + DB_SOUND_REF;
  return newdB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the best I got it down to is 3.8mA. I only got so far by leaving the voltage regulator and the internal oscillator (DFLL) on during sleeping.

After adding the following code to my setup routine, when board goes to sleep, the microphone still works after waking up:

```
SYSCTRL->DFLLCTRL.bit.RUNSTDBY=1; 
SYSCTRL->VREG.bit.RUNSTDBY=1;
```

However, ideally I would like to get much less than that, but then the mic doesn't work...